# Bootstrap progress bar only fires until half way

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have the following bootstrap progress bar:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" aria-valuemax="100" role="progressbar">
        <p id="ProgressPresentage"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do animate the progress bar using `setInterval` function by increasing the width by 10 each time the function `startProgressBar` gets called:

```
function startProgressBar() {
    percentVal += 10;
    progressBar.css("width", percentVal + '%');
    if (percentVal == 100) {
        percentVal = 0;
    }
}
```

I do use the `setInterval` within SignalR hub.client block of code as follows:

```
hub.client.SendAsync = function (status) {
    switch (status) {
        case "Adding":
            $("#DataProgress").text("Processing Data");
            document.getElementById("btnsubmit").disabled = true;
            intervalId = window.setInterval(startProgressBar,1);
            break;
    }
}
```

Then I do   `clearInterval(intervalId);` once I receive message completed from SginalR. The `intervalId` is predefined as int at the start of my code. The code seems to be working fine until it reaches 60 or 50% then it does not moves forward any more. Once I debug the code and I step into the code lines by lines progress bar completes until the end and rolls back again to zero and works fine. So what is the issue with my code why the progress bar only reaches half way.

```
hub.client.SendAsync = function (status) {
    switch (status) {
        case "Completed":
            clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<DataStructure>("https://localhost:44320/api/values", dataStructure);
    context.Clients.All.SendAsync("Adding");
    postTask.Wait();
    if(postTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        context.Clients.All.SendAsync("Completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code works when you step through it, it's probably related with sync/async. Try to increase `setInterval` to 100 milliseconds or 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

Comment: Yes, That was the case. I will try to post an answer.